# Bamboo in wood chipper?

Tags: wood

Can green/fresh bamboo be processed with any sort of wood chipper, or is it too hard?  If it can be chipped, what diameter seems to be the maximum?

Comment: why do you need to chip the bamboo?

Comment: Chipping/mulching bamboo might be my next cheaper alternative to instead somehow transporting it away.  I am not able to burn it.

Comment: Based on my experience with renting a large chipper I'd expect the likely issue would be clogging from the small frondy bits more than how hard it is (and hardness varies drastically with whether it's fresh/green or old/dried bamboo.) I was not chipping bamboo, but I was chipping trees with vines in them, and the vines would wrap rather than cut; I can imagine the smaller bamboo bits doing the same. Size you can process will depend very much on the size chipper you rent.

Comment: I would be careful trying to chip bamboo, we removed a growth of overgrown back yard bamboo and used a small 8 horse chipper, some of the stalks were 3-4 “ diameter and many twigs, the problem was the next month the entire back yard turned into a bamboo field so make sure to put down tarps to catch the chips it chips easily but any green wood will sprout as we found out , we ended up havering to use a temporary ground sterilization chemical that delayed flipping the home 3 months. We did find out that some nurseries will purchase the larger plants as they clone or grow faster.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, will keep in mind to maybe trim small fronds off before chipping, if I do end up trying chipping.

Comment: Oh wow @EdBeal, it sound like you are saying even the green chips that your chipper made, were able to sprout themselves.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes the chips we did not pick up did sprout it was a horrible mess. I had no idea that a little piece of live bamboo would sprout and grow so quickly.

Comment: Wow, that's insidious! My wife wants to line our back fence with a "bamboo living wall" and I think it's going to be a nightmare to keep it controlled. You just confirmed that.

Comment: Omg, no. Bamboo chips will not grow new plants. Not true bamboo, at least. Japanese knotweed can do that, and it's sometimes called bamboo but it absolutely is not. Bamboo will send up new shoots from the underground rhizomes after cutting all the culms down, but tiny little chips will not turn into new plants.

Comment: Any idea then what could have been happening in the case of @Ed Beal from their comments on the question?  Thanks.

Comment: I said what could be happening: the rhizomes Ed left in the ground produced new culms after he chipped the ones he cut down. Bamboo will produce new shoots from the rhizomes if it's cut down. The rhizomes of running bamboo can run underground anywhere from 10 to 30 feet from the nearest culm, unless contained or pruned. So when you cut down all of the culms, this triggers the plant to produce new culms all over.

Comment: You have to cut down this second flush of shoots as soon as they appear. This starves the rhizomes. The following spring, there should only be a few new shoots, unless it was an especially vigorous bamboo with lots of energy stored. However many there are, they must be completely cut down, removing any source of photosynthesis to continue to starve the rhizomes. As long as removal of top growth is prompt and complete, the rhizomes will quickly starve after a year. If any leaves are left, they can feed the rhizomes and the bamboo will persist for much longer.

Comment: These plants were a “grove” or whatever you call bamboo that is not contained some of the stalks or plants were 20’ tall if that is a weed ok but we cut it all down chipped and used a box ripper to pull the roots out , in the areas around the truck where the chipper was pointed no bamboo originally we had plants sprouting , the nursery that applied the temporary sterilizer said any twig or small piece of the plants would sprout and this was the only way to kill it and any roots we may have missed.